# how to disable uitouch on specific area of view when view is in panning/moving mode:iphone

Tags: iphone, uitouch, uipangesturerecognizer

i am working on the pdf based application, where i have implemented page curl effect with animation [from github](https://github.com/brow/leaves/downloads).this all works fine in non zoom mode.
when i do pinch in on a pdf it zooms in and i can move/pan in the pdf view.
Now as soon as i touch the area where the page curl animation is implemented the page starts curling in pinch/zoom view which looks very weired.something like this:

[image: toched the edges of the pdf page and result is something like this]

Any suggestions?
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't checked out the Github Framework for the Page Curl effect, but theoretically speaking. If you don't want it to page curl while in zoom, you would have to do an`if` statement to determine if it should begin the animation.

```
if(pdfIsZoomed) {
  //We dont do anything, because the PDF is zoomed.
} else {
  //PDF Isn't zoomed, continue with page curl.
}
```